# Unsuccessful looking for print variable $email in php on echo

Tags: php, postgresql

HTML

```
<form name="display" action="update.php" method="POST" >
    <li>Account Email:<input type="text" name="find_email" /></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" /></li>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$db     = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=CS2102 user=xxx password=xxx");
$email = $_POST['find_email'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = pg_query($db, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");       // Query template
$row    = pg_fetch_row($result);        // To store the result row
$count = pg_query($db, "SELECT count(*) FROM user");
if($db) echo "db connected" . "num of data " . pg_num_rows($count) ." . $email;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            echo "<ul><form name='update' action='update.php' method='POST' >
            <li>New Password:</li> 
            <li><input type='text' name='new_password' value='$row[password]' /></li>
        <li><input type='submit' name='new' /></li>
        </form>
    </ul>";
}

$password = $_POST['new_password'];
$email = $_POST['find_email'];
echo $email;
if (isset($_POST['new'])) { // Submit the update SQL command
    echo $password; 
    $sql = "'UPDATE user SET password = '$password'' WHERE email = '$email'";
    echo $sql . ":)";

}
```

It prints:

> 'UPDATE user SET password = '555'' WHERE  email := '':)

But the prior $email that I echo out went missing when I fill up the second form and click submit.

Comment: Please, format your post.

Comment: @Script47 may I check how do I do it?

Comment: Sure: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You need to get rid of all those `<br>` running rampant in your code. I cannot even edit that mess without knowing what is or is not your actual code.

Comment: I gave editing a shot, but too much time to fix completely.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks for the advice. But my school project requires us to use bitnami and we need to code everything by ourselves. That being said, I will look into your advice

Comment: How about retriving $email variable? The variable seen to exist but when I go on to the next form, it kinda disappear when I attempt to print the sql message :/

Comment: Nothing I said keeps you from coding it all yourself. Bitnami is just a code repo for the LAMP stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the email in the update password form too. In PhP, the variable wont be saved if the page refreshes, so you have to save it and again send it to process further. Please have a look at the following update.

P.S. Added hidden field in the second form to save the posted email from first form

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            echo "<ul><form name='update' action='update.php' method='POST' >
            <li>New Password:</li> 
            <input type='hidden' name='find_email' value='$_POST['find_email']' />
            <li><input type='text' name='new_password' value='$row[password]' /></li>
        <li><input type='submit' name='new' /></li>
        </form>
    </ul>";
}
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. That's a good idea! Didn't know the page refreshes everytime i click a button form :)

Comment: Yeah, clicking on submit button always redirect the page to the action page. Please upvote and mark as accepted answer if it worked